# ¿Cómo funciona una inspección negativa para coincidir con todo excepto números negativos?

Tags: javascript, regex

Según he leído los grupos se usan para combinar los tokens.

Estoy intentando marcar todos los caracteres, que **no** sean:

- Dígitos **negativos**

Input:

```
-9     ---> NO LO MARCARÍA ya que es un digito negativo
```

cualquier cosa que no sea -digito sí se marcará. El input es cualquier caracter (espacios, textos, digitos, caracteres especiales, etc.), y sería marcado cualquier caracter que no sea un dígito negativo. Necesito excluir a los que sean dígitos negativos.

Para los digitos negativos he realizado esto:

```
/[(?:-\d)]/g ,
```

Pero deseo marcar los que NO son negativos

He visto en otra pregunta, una respuesta que fue:

```
^(?!.*-\d).*$
```

Realmente funciona, pero ¿por qué debe ser así?

Intuitivamente, lo intenté hacer así:

```
/(^(?:-\d))/g
```

Usando como referencia que para negar cualquier clase de caracter, se usa:

```
[^abc]
```

Además vi que hacerlo con esta expresión:

```
^(?:(?!-\d).)+$
```

Es más rapido, pero por qué lo sería?

Sobre el funcionamiento:

- ¿Por qué se usa un `^`?

Hasta donde tengo entendido, eso es para el comienzo de la cadena o de negación de clase de caracteres, pero entonces,

- ¿Por qué lo usa ahí?
- ¿Por qué usa un grupo capturador `(?:)`

Me gustaría saber cómo funciona la expresión regular en su conjunto, pero también cómo funciona independientemente para así comprenderla mejor.

Comment: ya lo edite, en resumen quiere marcar cualquier cosa que no sea un digito negativo con regex

Comment: el input es cualquier caracter, y seria marcado cualquier caracter que no sea un digito negativo e intentandolo con ^ de set negativo, pero es solo para clases de caracteres

Comment: el input puede ser cualquier cosa, espacios, textos, digitos, caracteres especiales, etc. Pero necesito excluir a los que sean digitos negativos, por eso hice -\d , pero nosé como negarlo, por eso lo de negative lockahead que lo vi en otra respuesta, pero no explicaban como funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Análisis de tus intentos

> Para los digitos negativos he realizado esto:
>
> ```
> /[(?:-\d)]/g
> ```

`[(?:-\d)]` lo único que hace es coincidir con 1 único caracter, que puede ser `(`, `?`, `:`, un dígito (`\d`), o `)`. Cuando usás corchetes, estás especificando una clase de caracteres. Eso significa que coincide con 1 y sólo 1 caracter dentro de los que están declarados.

> Intuitivamente, lo intenté hacer así:
>
> ```
> /(^(?:-\d))/g
> ```

Un `^` sirve para negar una clase de caracteres, pero sólo cuando está dentro de una clase de caracteres, nada más. Cuando está afuera, en el patrón, tiene un significado completamente diferente. `^` coincide con la posición del inicio del texto. No sirve para negar nada, y negar con expresiones regulares no es algo que se haga tan directo. Nada más, con la posición al inicio del texto.

---

#### 2. Sobre las expresiones que encontraste

> He visto en otra pregunta, una respuesta que fué:
>
> ```
> ^(?!.*-\d).*$
> ```
>
> Realmente funciona, pero por qué debe ser así ?

`(?!patrón)` es una inspección negativa (*negative lookahead*). Lo que hace es dar una "espiada" hacia adelante. Se fija que la posición actual *no esté seguida por un texto que coincida con el patrón*.

Pero tiene la particularidad de que no consume caracteres. Luego de intentar la inspección, el cursor sigue estando en la posición en la que estaba antes. Y el texto con el que podría coincidir, no forma parte del fragmento de texto con el que coincide la expresión regular en su totalidad.

Al ser una inspección *negativa*, hace que todo el regex pueda coincidir si el patrón de la inspección no coincide. Es eso: que la posición actual no esté seguida por algo.

`^(?!.*-\d)` coincide con la posición inicial, y se fija que esa posición **no esté seguida por**:

- `.*` cualquier cantidad de caracteres (excepto saltos de línea)
- `-\d` un menos y un dígito.

O sea, que recorre toda la línea buscando que no haya un `-\d`. Sólo si no lo hubiera, es que el resto del patrón del regex puede seguir intentando coincidir.

Luego, `.*` coincide con toda la línea.

Básicamente se está recorriendo todo el string 2 veces: 1 con la inspección negativa, y otra con el `.*` principal (sólo si la inspección no hizo que fallara la coincidencia global).

De esa forma, se garantizó que no hubiese un número negativo. Sólo si no coincide es que el resto del regex puede seguir coincidiendo con toda la línea.

> Además vi que hacerlo con esta expresión:
>
> ```
> ^(?:(?!-\d).)+$
> ```
>
> Por qué se usa un `^`, hasta
>   donde tengo entendido eso es para el comienzo de la cadena

Usa un `^` justamente para eso, para anclarlo al inicio del texto. Si no estuviese, podría coincidir con, por ejemplo:

```
antes de un negativo -1 después de un negativo
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

porque a partir de esa posición, no hay nada que esté seguido por un `-\d`. O sea, si no tuviese el `^`, como no estaría anclado al inicio, puede coincidir en cualquier parte del string, logrando un resultado que no se desea.

Incluso, sin el `^`, coincidiría con `12345` en

```
-12345
 ^^^^^
```

porque desde esa posición en adelante, no hay nada que esté seguido por un `-\d`. Es decir, después de pasar el `-`, no hay nada que *no esté seguido por un menos y un dígito*.

> porqué usa un grupo capturador `(?:)`

Todo lo contrario, es un grupo no capturador.

Ese grupo no capturador `(?:(?!-\d).)+` sirve para agrupar el subpatrón que está adentro y poder repetir todo con el `+` (1 o más veces).

Es decir, que va a repetir `(?!-\d).`

- Si no está seguido por un `-\d`,
- coincide con 1 caracter.

Es lo mismo que un bucle. Está recorriendo el string caracter por caracter, coincidiendo si y sólo si no está seguido por el inicio de un número negativo.

[image: representación en regexper.com] <sup>Fuente: [regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#(%3F%3A(%3F!-%5Cd).)%2B)</sup>

---

**Ojo:** Estas dos expresiones no "*marcan*" el resto del texto que no es un negativo. Lo que hacen es verificar que en todo el string no haya un negativo y, si no hay, coinciden con toda la línea.

**Ojo2:** Todas estas fallarían con el número `-.5`.

> `^(?:(?!-\d).)+$` Es más rapido, pero por qué lo sería?

¿Es más rápido? Sí para algunos casos sencillos, pero no necesariamente para cualquier caso. Como todo en regex, depende del texto con el que se compare. Por ejemplo, armé este ejemplo en [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/lookahead-inicial-vs-lookahead-en-loop/1) donde `^(?!.*-\d).*$` (con el lookahead inicial) se evalúa más rápido (1.15% en el 1.2 millones de ejecuciones por segundo en lo que probé recién).

No obstante, es de esperar que se de el caso contario para textos donde el signo `-` esté como primer caracter del texto. ¿Por qué? Porque el regex con el lookahead en un loop intenta encontrar el `-` en el primer caracter antes de seguir.

- `^(?:(?!-\d).)+$` Primero, y sólo si no está seguido por `-\d`, intenta coincidir con el primer caracter. Por eso, fallaría en el primer paso con textos como `-123`, en los que el `-` lo hace fallar inmediatamente.
- `^(?!.*-\d).*$` en cambio, primero intenta barrer toda la línea con `.*` y luego va haciendo backtracking caracter por caracter (desde el final al inicio), intentando coincidir con `-\d`. Por eso, es que en el ejemplo del JSPerf, tiene un mejor desempeño con texto donde el `-` está más cerca del final de la línea.

Pero también depende mucho del lenguaje en el que estés. Cada lenguaje tiene su propio dialecto de regex, con un motor completamente diferente. Y JavaScript es, por lejos, dentro de los lenguajes comúnmente utilizados, el que tiene el peor motor de expresiones regulares. Este resultado puede no ser así en otros lenguajes (pero igual, siempre depende del texto con el que lo compares). Cada motor de expresiones regulares tiene su conjunto de optimizaciones. Y cada optimización lo que busca es hacer que una expresión que no va a coincidir falle lo antes posible. Por ejemplo, Perl tiene las más asombrosas optimizaciones, haciendo que muchas veces que una expresión va a fallar, ni siquiera entre en el código del motor de regex para intentarlo, fallando antes.

Si realmente estás buscando una expresión que recorra caracter por caracter viendo que no esté seguido por un patrón, existe una técnica llamada *unrolling the loop* que posee muchísima mejor performance que las anteriores. Este caso, llevado a un *unrolling the loop* sería:

```
^[^-]*(?:-(?!\d)[^-]*)*$
```

Y, para demostrarlo, un nuevo JSPerf en https://jsperf.com/lookahead-inicial-vs-en-loop-vs-unrolling-the-loop/1

En Chrome 61, me dio

```
Lookahead inicial                444,977
/^(?!.*-\d).*$/                  ±3.40%
                                 60% más lento

Lookahead en loop                801,615
/^(?:(?!-\d).)+$/                ±4.00%
                                 29% más lento

Unrolling the loop               1,112,335
/^[^-]*(?:-(?!\d)[^-]*)*$/       ±2.24%
                                 el más rápido
```

Pero, de nuevo, esto es desde la teoría y ajustado a textos con casos genéricos. Para cada texto, habrá uno que se comporte mejor que el otro. Y para cada motor, tendrás un conjunto de optimizaciones diferentes.

---

#### 3. Cómo ver si un número no es negativo

¡Olvidate de regex! Usá al propio lenguaje.

```
if (numero < 0) {
    console.log('Te aseguro que es muchísimo más rápido que con regex');
}
```

---

#### 4. Sólo para aprender, cómo sería con regex?

La mejor forma no es negar un patrón, sino negar el resultado de una expresión regular. Si te interesa ver que no haya un negativo en el texto, buscamos que coincida con `-\d`, y luego negamos el resultado:

```
if ( ! /-\d/.test(texto) ) {
    // Ok, no tiene números negativos
}
```

O, si te interesa eliminarlos del texto, buscamos coincidir con los negativos (lo presento con decimales y exponente por completitud):

```
/-\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:e[-+]?\d+)?/gi
```

Y los reemplazamos por `""` para eliminarlos.

```
textoSinNegativos = texto.replace(/-\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:e[-+]?\d+)?/gi, '');
```

> el input es cualquier caracter, y seria marcado cualquier caracter que no sea un digito negativo

Si la idea es separar cada uno de los fragmentos que no son números negativos, usaríamos `split()` para obtener cada parte por separado.

```
> 'abcd -123 def'.split(/-\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:e[-+]?\d+)?/gi)

< ["abcd ", " def"]
```